# How to save a file in a variable in SwiftUI 2

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have got the URL of a file using file importer. Now I want to store the file in a variable so that I can send it to the server.

```
.fileImporter(isPresented: $openfile, allowedContentTypes: [.audio,.pdf,.png, .text, .jpeg], allowsMultipleSelection: false) { (res) in
            
            do{
                let fileURL = try res.get()
                //getting file name
                self.fileName = fileURL.last?.lastPathComponent ?? "File Uplaoded"
                print(fileURL)
            }catch{
                print("Error reading docs")
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
```

How can I save the file in a variable from the fileURL?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/64975570/12299030?

Comment: No it does not, I have to upload different documents, like PDF, image, audio, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stackoverflow answer shows you how to go about getting the file content.
You have to adapt the answer to your code, something like:

```
 var fileData: Data?
 
 .fileImporter(isPresented: $openfile, allowedContentTypes: [.audio,.pdf,.png, .text, .jpeg], allowsMultipleSelection: false) { (res) in           
        do{
            let fileURL = try res.get()
            if let url = fileURL.first {
                fileName = url.lastPathComponent
                fileData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                print("\n fileName: \(fileName) \n url: \(url) \n fileData: \(fileData)")
            }
        }catch{
            print("Error reading docs")
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

Then you can use fileData to send to the server.

Comment: I can save the data now after a little tweak of the code:  fileData = try Data(contentsOf: URL(from: fileURL as! Decoder)), I will mark it as correct if I can send the data to the server.

Comment: not convince about: fileData = try Data(contentsOf: URL(from: fileURL as! Decoder))

I would just use: if let url = fileURL.first { fileData = try Data(contentsOf: url) }