# How to read file line by line with App Sandbox enabled?

Tags: swift, macos, file, swiftui, appstore-sandbox

[image]

I have to read a file line by line, so I made sure I could select a file and then call a function to read it by passing the path.

But I get the following error:

```json
An error took place: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “30.160625.txt”
 couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." 
UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/nameUser/Downloads/ask%20us/30.160625.txt, 
NSUnderlyingError=0x600002a68cc0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
```

I have App Sandbox enabled, as the appstore does not accept apps where it is disabled.

Can anyone help me out?

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var path = "/Users/Documents"
    
    func readFile(){
        do {
            let contentFromFile = try NSString(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            print(contentFromFile)
        }catch let error as NSError {
            print("An error took place: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            TextField("Path", text: $path)
                .padding(.vertical, 8)
                .padding(.horizontal, 8)
                .padding(.leading, 22)
                .padding(.trailing, 22)
                .cornerRadius(8)
                .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
                .overlay(
                    HStack{
                        Button(action: {
                            let panel = NSOpenPanel()
                            let launcherLogPathWithTilde = path as NSString
                            let expandedLauncherLogPath = launcherLogPathWithTilde.expandingTildeInPath
                            panel.directoryURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: expandedLauncherLogPath, isDirectory: true)
                            panel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
                            panel.canChooseDirectories = false
                            panel.canChooseFiles = true
                            if panel.runModal() == .OK {
                                self.path = panel.url?.absoluteString.replacingOccurrences(of: "file://", with: "") ?? "<none>"
                                readFile()
                            }
                        }){
                            Image(systemName: "folder.fill")
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                .padding(.leading, 8)
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                    }
                )
        }
        .frame(width: 500, height: 200)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Edit:
Seems to work, what do you think?

```swift
func readFile(){
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        do {
            //var row: Subtitle = Subtitle()
            var number: Int = 0
            var start: String = ""
            var end: String = ""
            var text: String = ""
            
            try String(contentsOf: url, encoding: .utf8)
                .split(separator: "\n")
                .forEach { line in
                    let n = Int(line)
                    if n != nil {
                        number = n!
                    } else if(line.contains("-->")){
                        print(line)
                        let matched = matches(for: "[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+,[0-9]+", in: String(line))
                        print(matched)
                        start = matched[0]
                        end = matched[1]
                        //print("Time: \(line)")
                    } else {
                        text = String(line)
                        let row = Subtitle(number: number, start: start, end: end, text: text)
                        arrayS.append(row)
                    }
                }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("An error took place: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: For starters, use the url instead of a path when reading the file and don’t use NSString.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: I tried that, but it doesn't work either.
```func readFile(){ let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path) do {
            try String(contentsOf: url, encoding: .utf8)
                .split(separator: "\n")
                .forEach { line in
                    print("line: \(line)")
                }
        }catch let error as NSError {
            print("An error took place: \(error)")
        }
    }```

Comment: But it’s a better way to do it and I didn’t say it would solve your specific issue.

Comment: And I meant that you should completely skip the path so change your @State property as well to be of type URL

Comment: Remember in the app sandbox, all your paths will be referential to the app container, not the users' operating system.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of hardcoding paths, which is incorrect in SandBox, use URL retrieved via `NSFileManager` API for needed domain (user in your case)

```
    /* -URLForDirectory:inDomain:appropriateForURL:create:error: is a URL-based replacement for FSFindFolder(). It allows for the specification and (optional) creation of a specific directory for a particular purpose (e.g. the replacement of a particular item on disk, or a particular Library directory.
     
        You may pass only one of the values from the NSSearchPathDomainMask enumeration, and you may not pass NSAllDomainsMask.
     */
    @available(iOS 4.0, *)
    open func url(for directory: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory, in domain: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask, appropriateFor url: URL?, create shouldCreate: Bool) throws -> URL
```

This API takes sandbox into account and provides valid URLs, which in pair of `NSURL.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource` can be used to read corresponding file content.

See also for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/64975570/12299030

Comment: I didn't understand how to use the function you wrote for app on mac os.

In the example you suggested I can't find the function you wrote.

I edited the question, let me know what you think of the method.