# NSProgress not working with sandboxed items?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sandbox, foundation, nsprogress

I'm creating an NSProgress object to show a progress indicator underneat a file in my Downloads directory. The entitlements includes `com.apple.security.files.downloads.read-write`.
The indicator does not show when `NSProgressFileURLKey` points to the sandboxed file path, e.g. `/Users/mdbraber/Library/Containers/com.mdbraber.TestApp/Data/Downloads/Test.pptx.download`. It does work when `NSProgressFileURLKey` points to the direct download location which the sandbox links to e.g. `/Users/mdbraber/Downloads/Test.pptx.download`

Is this a bug or should I use something else for NSProgressFileURLKey to make this work?

```
#define KdownloadsPath NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDownloadsDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES).firstObject

_downloadedPath = [KdownloadsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
_downloadingPath = [_downloadedPath stringByAppendingString:@".download"];

NSDictionary* info = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        @"NSProgressFileOperationKindDownloading", @"NSProgressFileOperationKindKey",
        [NSURL fileURLWithPath:_downloadingPath], @"NSProgressFileURLKey",
        nil];

self.progress = [[NSProgress alloc] initWithParent:nil userInfo:info];
[self.progress setKind:@"NSProgressKindFile"];
[self.progress setPausable:NO];
[self.progress setCancellable:YES];
[self.progress setTotalUnitCount:_totalBytes];
[self.progress publish];
```

(updating the progress indicator happens elsewhere)

Comment: Tip: use URLs instead of paths.

Comment: @Willeke it's constructing a fileURL based on the path - should I do something different?

Comment: See [How to read file line by line with App Sandbox enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68485123/how-to-read-file-line-by-line-with-app-sandbox-enabled)